# Get quote items from admin quote session

Tags: orders, magento-1, quote, admin-order-create

I want to set shipping price for orders created in magento admin, how to get the quote items?
I am using below code to get all the Quote

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote();
```

I put log for above line and I am getting "1" in log.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set custom shipping price then you have to create a custom shipping module .Or you can set flat shipping rate from Magento admin -> configuration -> shipping method.

You can create shipping module using this link or google about how to create shipping method in Magento

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Shipping rates are collected by calling collectRates(). This function takes shipping information as a parameter and returns all available rates. It is also responsible for determining which rate is available for given request